# Are AWS EC2 key-pairs compromised when an EC2 instance is compromised?

Tags: ssh, aws

Suppose I have multiple EC2 instances deployed with the same key-pair. The key-pair is used for SSH access and general troubleshooting. If one instance is compromised, do I need to be concerned about the key-pair allowing access to the other instances?
What kind of cryptographic primitive is used for EC2 key-pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of cryptographic primitive is used for EC2 key-pairs?

[The keys that Amazon EC2 uses are 2048-bit SSH-2 RSA keys.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)  They are asymmetric, "public key" pairs.  The public key goes on the instance(s) you wish to authenticate to, and the private key stays with you.

> If one instance is compromised, do I need to be concerned about the
> key-pair allowing access to the other instances?

No.  Because only the public key is compromised, there is no concern; that's why it's a "public" key.  Even when you authenticate to a compromised instance, the private key itself is not shared with the instance.

Comment: Thanks, this makes things clear!